# Layout of Vuetify v-btn and v-input in a v-card-action area

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need some help with aligning some v-btn's and a v-input.  I'm trying to create a Record Navigation control and I need it to align in the horizontal middle.  What I have is [image]

And what I need is [image]

My code is

```
          <v-card-action>  
              <v-layout row d-flex class="text-center">
                <div class="my-15 ml-15 text-center">                     
                  <v-btn
                    class="ma-2"
                    text
                    round
                    color="primary"
                    @click="navChange('first')"
                  >First</v-btn>
                  <v-btn
                    class="ma-2"
                    text
                    round
                    color="primary"
                    @click="navChange('previous')"
                  >Previous</v-btn>
                  <v-text-field width="10px" v-model="recordNav" class="centered-input"></v-text-field>

                  <v-btn class="ma-2" text round color="primary" @click="navChange('next')">Next</v-btn>
                  <v-btn class="ma-2" text round color="primary" @click="navChange('last')">Last</v-btn>
                </div>
                <div class="my-15"></div>                  
              </v-layout>                
            </v-card-action>
```

and have some codepen code at

https://codepen.io/morgenweck/pen/yLLdydN

I'm new to Vue and it seems that some standard HTML code does not work the same in a v-card-action area.  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have refined the layout to be more in line with your goal.

The primary issues were:

- typo in `v-card-actions` opening tag -- actions is plural
- to set the `flex-direction` of the buttons container to `no-wrap` (I substituted a `v-row` to use props for this)
- the `round` prop is deprecated on buttons so we need to use `rounded` now
- remove the `text` prop so that we can get the pill shape and background color of the buttons

I also set a defined `width` on the buttons so they are all the same size and added left, right padding on the button container.

*I recommend viewing the snippet in full-screen so you don't see the console messages as prominently.*

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    //
    recordNav: "Record: 1 of 15"
  })
  
})
```

```css
.centered-input input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.11/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.11/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-actions>  
          <v-row row d-flex nowrap align="center" justify="center" class="px-2">
            <v-btn
              class="ma-2"
              rounded
              width="6.5rem"
              color="primary"
              @click="navChange('first')"
            >First</v-btn>
            <v-btn
              class="ma-2"
              rounded
              width="6.5rem"
              color="primary"
              @click="navChange('previous')"
            >Previous</v-btn>
            <v-text-field width="10px" v-model="recordNav" class="centered-input"></v-text-field>

            <v-btn 
              class="ma-2"
              rounded
              width="6.5rem"
              color="primary"
              @click="navChange('next')"
            >Next</v-btn>
            <v-btn
              class="ma-2"
              rounded
              width="6.5rem"
              color="primary"
              @click="navChange('last')"
            >Last</v-btn>
            
            <div class="my-15"></div>                  
          </v-row>                
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply not wrap them in `v-card-actions` if it works that way.

If it still doesn't, try putting each component in a column and use the tag `col="2"` for the buttons and `col="4"` for the input field like this:

(And use `v-row` instead of `v-layout`)

```
<v-row class="text-center">
  <div class="my-15 ml-15 text-center">
    <v-col cols="2">
      <v-btn
        class="ma-2"
        text
        round
        color="primary"
        @click="navChange('first')"
      >
        First
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2">
      <v-btn
        class="ma-2"
        text
        round
        color="primary"
        @click="navChange('previous')"
      >
        Previous
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="4">
      <v-text-field
        width="10px"
        v-model="recordNav"
        class="centered-input"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="2">
      <v-btn
        class="ma-2"
        text
        round
        color="primary"
        @click="navChange('next')"
      >
        Next
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="2">
      <v-btn
        class="ma-2"
        text
        round
        color="primary"
        @click="navChange('last')"
      >
        Last
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>
  </div>
  <div class="my-15"></div>
</v-row>
```

You use the `cols` attribute to determine how much space an element should take up in a row. The maximum value is 12. So if you want two elements in a row next to each other, you give them the attributes `cols="6"`, if you want 3 elements in a row then you give them `cols="4"` (since 12/3=4), etc. you get the idea.

On bigger screens (`cols` is for phones) you can align your elements differently. For instance you can place each of your elements in a new row if you give them the attribute `cols="12"` but if you want to have 2 elements in the same row on a tablet you use sm="6" on both elements. If you want your elements to have the same position no matter the screen size you can simply use `cols` on all of your `col` tags.

You can read further at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids